# Is there a Polars expressions API way to get the number of elements in a list in a cell?

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

Is there a Polars expressions API way to get the length of a list in a cell? For example, if column "fruits" has a row with ["apple", "banana"], I'd like to create a column n_fruits which has value 2 for that row.

I tried [.len()](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.len.html) and [.count()](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.count.html#polars.count), but those both count the number of rows in the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.list`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/list.html) namespace so it's `.list.len()`